# user @ localhost already exists. can't create test user for second database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm doing testing on a separate mySQL database and I would like to have one test user 'john' for that database. The problem is that user exists on another testing database for a different project. I would like to just use one user 'john' for my host 'localhost' on all of my different test databases, but it won't let me because that user exists in a different database.

Is there a way to use my user 'john' for all of my test databases or do I need to make a different user every time I want to test something? Because it already exists, I tried to just use it, but access was denied.

I mean I could just create new users every time I want to work on a different project, or test something else, but that seems unnecessary, and undesirable.

TIA :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need try out something like this from your MySQL prompt.

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO john@localhost identified by 'johnspassword';
flush privileges;
```

Check [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-create-a-new-user-and-grant-permissions-in-mysql) too.

Comment: Thank you. Is this safe to have global access like this? It's showing up in the list of users now, but am I more prone to attacks because of  having this set up this way?

Comment: This is really not a good way to do this. The `*.*` should be replaced by a database name which you need to assign john as user. The above command assigns john with full privileges on the databases available which i personally think its not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

First check your current rights;

```
mysql> show grants for 'john'@'localhost';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for john'@'localhost                                                                |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '0cdf93684d757e1f'         |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_database_1`.* TO 'john'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION        |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And then do a 'GRANT ALL'. If you leave out the password then mysql will keep the current password;

```
mysql> grant all on *.* to 'john'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)

mysql> show grants for 'john'@'localhost';
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for stubby@127.0.0.1                                                                   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'john'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '0cdf93684d757e1f'   |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `test_database_1`.* TO 'john'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION       |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

And that should do it.